# Umbraco V7xx Inserting HTML5 Video to webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html5-video, umbraco, umbraco7

So I have created a document type in umbraco with corresponding template for my video section, which I want it to be content manageable and don't want to embed from youtube or similar. I have changed the upload limit for umbraco in webconfig and uploaded the vid in media section, using media picker. The problem I have now is how to fetch it from that media and display it on my home page. I have this code in my partial view, which is for that section but it's not display anything to the page and not showing any errors on the console:

Edit: I tried a new way, it's giving me this error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
(as soon as I remove ".Url" the page works but it doesn't load the path to the video in media! :(

```
    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

<!--===================================Setion 2 SO Wifi & Customer Reviews=========================================-->
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 wifi">
            <h2 class="so-wifi">
                @Umbraco.Field("sowifiTitle", convertLineBreaks: true)
            </h2>
            <img src="/src/img/so wifi.png" class="img-fluid wifi-img" alt="so wifi">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="video embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
             @{
                var videoId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("sowifiVideo");
                var videoUrl = Umbraco.Media(videoId).Url;

                <video autoplay controls width="850" height="450">
                    <source src="@videoUrl" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                } 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried to do yourself to fix? Could you check what HTML code is being generated? Have you tried debugging your way through? Are you getting a proper mediaFolderId? Are you actually picking a media folder on your content? What type of object are you then getting in the .Children() collection?

You aren't using your "video" variable in the loop, you are requesting a property of the current page instead. If you're lucky you might be able to do something like

```
src="@video.Url"
```

instead of the whole Model.Content thing, but it's very unclear from your question whether it might actually work :-/

**EDIT**: you should be able to do something like this to get a single Media URL:

```
var videoId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("sowifiVideo");
var videoUrl = Umbraco.Media(videoId).Url;
```

and then

```
<source src="@videoUrl" type="video/mp4" />
```

When you do images and use GetCropUrl(...) then, funnily enough, that function gets the URL for you. With any other kind of media file you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I have tried  a new way now following tutorial on codeshare.uk but it's breaking my page completely now with that error. First post edited.

Comment: Okay. So now the loop is gone? Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("sowifiVideo") will try to return an IPublishedContent object, but if you have simply picked a Media item inside Umbraco the property will not magically hold the video "object". It's more likely to just be a media ID. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I used the same "Model.Content" for images, I have uploaded images in media section and got their ID and posted them to the webpage, also resized them as well using .GetCropUrl.....why is the same thing not working for video which is also uploaded in media section of umbraco? Sorry,I am very new to umbraco and pretty much everything. When I remove ".Url" from Model.Content the webpage loads normally with video windows on which it says: "No video wit supported format and MIME type found"...

Comment: Answer updated. It's the same procedure as with images, although images have a number of helper methods built in. Hope we got it this time!

Comment: thanks for the help and making me better understand this although it's not working yet, could you show me how would you implement this on my code in first post in a new post?

Comment: You are welcome! But you have to be more specific than "it's not working" then. I'm not a mind reader. Help me help you - be as specific and exhaustive in your description of the problem as you can, and update the question (best way to do it is to add to existing text).

Comment: I have added your code to mine and updated the first post, unfortunately my video is still not loading on the page and I get the same error no supported format or MIME type found. The page works at least and I am not getting yellow screen now. Console error is: Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed. 
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.

Comment: How does the generated HTML look? Is the src parameter empty?

Comment: Wild idea, but you could try debugging. Or even outputting stuff as raw text instead of putting it into the video element. Just to, you know, debug stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved, going to post the code that works here just in case someone else has a similar problem in the future.(thx for the help Jannik once again to forward me in the right direction)

```
            @{
                var videoId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("sowifiVideo");
                foreach (var item in videoId)
                {
                    <video controls width="850" height="450">
                        <source src="@item.Url" type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                }
             }
```